# How to poll data using Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to poll my data in HighCharts. The graph in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/live-data) link is what I am trying to achieve. I am using Ajax request to retrieve my data. Here is my code:

```
setInterval(RefreshGraph, 3000);

...

...

function RefreshGraph() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Text'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'TIMEFRAME'
                    },
                    categories: ['-4m', '-3m', '-2m', '-1m', 'Now']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {

                        text: 'NUMBER'
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    crosshairs: true,
                    shared: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        marker: {
                            radius: 4,
                            lineColor: '#666666',
                            lineWidth: 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{}]
            };

        Highcharts.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetData",
            success: function (data) {
                var formattedData = FormatData(data);
                //Graph 1
                options.series[0] = formattedData[0];
                //Graph 2
                options.series[1] = formattedData[1];

                Highcharts.chart("container", options);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, the entire graph gets redrawn with my above code. How can I enable live polling for the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You create a chart every time data is received. You need to create a chart and then update it. Example:

```
const options = {...};

const chart = Highcharts.chart("container", options);

function RefreshGraph() {
  Highcharts.ajax({
    url: "/Home/GetData",
    success: function(data) {
      var formattedData = FormatData(data);

      chart.update({
        series: [formattedData[0], formattedData[1]]
      });
    }
  });
}

setInterval(RefreshGraph, 3000);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6d5stjab/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: Hi. The above works, but the graph does not shift as described in the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/live-data)

Comment: Hi @Meeth46, Please try to use `setData` method. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jkymz3hr/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: thank you for all the guidance. I was able to solve it by following the example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update